# creating multiple tables with single sql command

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I searched for this here and on google and surprisingly couldn't find an answer. I tried to create syntax to submit to mysql that would create multiple tables with the same columns, but it returned an error. Can you point out what is wrong with my syntax, or if this is even possible?

```
 CREATE TABLE news, life
 (
 id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 name varchar( 30 ) ,
 email varchar( 50 ) ,
 COMMENT text,
 datetime datetime,
 ip varchar( 20 )
 )
```

Comment: Multiple tables, all with the same columns? Are you sure you want to do this at all? Have you thought about adding a "type" column that has values of "news" or "life"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible like that.

Think about your table design. This sounds like you should consider creating a single table and adding another column `type` that will be `news` or `life` (or a reference to another table defining types).

---

If you really need two tables, create your first table:

```
 CREATE TABLE news
 (
 id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 name varchar( 30 ) ,
 email varchar( 50 ) ,
 COMMENT text,
 datetime datetime,
 ip varchar( 20 )
 )
```

and then

```
CREATE TABLE life AS ( SELECT * FROM news where 1=2 );
```

Indexes and constraints (`UNIQUE`, `PRIMARY KEY`, `FOREIGN KEY`) will not be copied though. You will have to handle them yourself.

Comment: peter,

thanks for your response. appreciate the concern about the table design, it is actually much more complex than that, i was just using a small example. can you explain where 1=2? would that code change if i'm creating more than 2 tables?

Comment: Still not sure why you need more than one table... Using `1=2` makes sure that no rows are returned (this would actually copy content of `news` to `life` otherwise). Code will be the same when creating more than one table. See my edit about indexes and constraints.

Answer (score 3):

you are in mysql so you can use the `LIKE` clause of the `CREATE TABLE` command; that way you will also get column attributes and indexes copied over e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

> Use LIKE to create an empty table
>   based on the definition of another
>   table, including any column attributes
>   and indexes defined in the original
>   table:  CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE
>   orig_tbl; The copy is created using
>   the same version of the table storage
>   format as the original table. The
>   SELECT privilege is required on the
>   original table.  LIKE works only for
>   base tables, not for views.  CREATE
>   TABLE ... LIKE does not preserve any
>   DATA DIRECTORY or INDEX DIRECTORY
>   table options that were specified for
>   the original table, or any foreign key
>   definitions.